# Fetching array from online database for android app using volley

Tags: java, php, android, database, android-volley

First I have to tell that I'm pretty new to android studio & PHP.

I have managed to make an application with login, uploading and searching the online database.

I used volley with the method POST.

Everything is fine & perfect if the search result is single.

The problem is when there is more than one result that need to be stored in an array. In this case my code is retrieving only the last result.

I know there are a lot of other methods available online but as I'm new I wasn't able to understand them and thus edit them according to my data.

Here is my JAVA MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.dell.myapplicationo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
    final TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvb);
    final Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c);


    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etname.getText().toString();


            // Response received from the server
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            String family = jsonResponse.getString("family");
                            String date= jsonResponse.getString("date");
                            String time= jsonResponse.getString("time");



                            // Display 
                            String message = name + family + date + time;
                            b.setText(message);


                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Not Found")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(name, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            queue.add(searchRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my SearchRequest class code:

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SearchRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://MYURL.hol.es/search.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public SearchRequest(String name, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

Finally here is my php code (search.php)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.in", "username", "password", "db");

    $name= $_POST["name"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $suspect);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $name, $family, $date, $time);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true; 
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["family"] = $family;
        $response["date"] = $date;
        $response["time"] = $time;



    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, after each iteration, you are overriding previous value here

```
 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true; 
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["family"] = $family;
        $response["date"] = $date;
        $response["time"] = $time;

    }
```

You can probably change above code as :

```
$response = array();
$arr = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true; 
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["family"] = $family;
    $response["date"] = $date;
    $response["time"] = $time;
    $arr[] = $response;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I know this information
PHP is not my core problem. I could have used instead the following method:
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      
but again I don't know how to receive it in JAVA 
If you kindly show me how to decode it in JAVA I will be very thankful.

Comment: java changes depends on your json encoding.